# Invalid value for cell

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to populate my table customers in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I am getting the following error. [image]the

I am new to SQL and if anyone has encountered this type of error, would be grateful to share it.

**Edit #1** Here are most of the tables

[image]

Comment: you should change the datatype of column organisationname to varchar.

Comment: check your table schema against column

Comment: I changed organisationName to nvarchar(50) but is giving me the same error. And the other fields are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and it helped closing and reopening the solution, granted one has the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You use **varbinary** type for organisationname,and try insert value of string format "Microsoft".Change the datatype to varchar or insert in column binary data.

Comment: I changed organisationName to nvarchar(50) but is giving me the same error message. And the other fields are immutable

Comment: Post screen of design table